# how to enable control on form based on user action on user control without requiring post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

My web page has a user control and a Save button. User control has several radio buttons, combo box, text box etc. The save button on the web page should only be enabled when user changes option on radio button, combo box or value in text box. Ideally I would like to enable  this save button from javascript (without requiring a post back) but not sure how to do it given that all those controls that can change are on a user control ( and not on the page itself). Any ideas/suggestions on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write java script in user control and try to get save button which is in web page then you will get button control on run time because your user control is part of your web page on run time.

so, Call one java script on radio button/combo box change event and enable/disable your button based on requirement.

Let me know if you have any question.

User control code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
            document.getElementById("btnSave").disabled = true;
    }
```

Call above test function on radio button onclick event

Web page (parent page)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="save" runat="server" />
```

aslo, add your user control here...

Comment: Problem is even is going to be fired on user control java-script. How the parent page on client side can know about this?

Comment: you are adding your user control on parent web page right? then when it will run .. it will treat as one web page only so even if you write javascript in user control and try to get button which is parent page then also your java script will work.

Comment: that will require a post back and handling of it on server side. Whole point of this question is to handle it on client side without requiring post back

Comment: here i am writing little code for your reference

Javascript in user control

function test() {
    document.getElementById("btnSave").disabled = true;
  }

  all your <asp:RadioButton ID="rdo" onclick="test()" runat="server"  code goes here
  
in your web page
here add your user control tag <uc1:userControl ID="userControl"
button code <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="save"

I hope this will help you.

Comment: can you include code in your answer? Its very hard to read code from comments.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this idea and let you know if there are any other questions